# Call sudo from Jenkins

Tags: sudo, tty, non-root-user, jenkins

I have one build machine which has a user `abc` which is has limited sudo access. When I check out the source code and run my build script, it works fine. The build script contains `sudo` calls for which it does not say "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified". But when I did same thing with Jenkins on a build machine added as slave, it shows "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified".

I have found one solution saying to comment out `Default requiretty` in the file `/etc/sudoers`. But I don’t have access to this file.

How I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Is this command you're trying to run via `sudo` allowed to run without entering a password? If you have to enter a password, sudo is going to require a tty.

Comment: Yes ..it runs without entering a password

Answer (score 4):

It fails, because `sudo` is trying to prompt on root password and there is no pseudo-tty allocated.

You've to either log-in as root or set-up the following rules in your `/etc/sudoers`
 (or: `sudo visudo`):

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges.
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Then make sure that your Jenkins user belongs to `admin` group (or `wheel`).

Ideally (safer) it would be to limit root privileges only to specific commands which can be specified as `%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/program`

Comment: It still requires a TTY.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options, comment out the `Defaults requiretty` setting  from /etc/sudoers as you mentioned or use the pseudo-tty allocation (`-t`) argument for `ssh`.

Try the following in your jenkins script:

`ssh -t 127.0.0.1 "sudo command"`

Although you will have to have `ssh` pre-shared keys configured to yourself and run it once manually to add an entry to known hosts, alternatively add the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` argument to `ssh` to ignore this.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do it
[image]

```
$ sudo visudo
## Now add the below lines in your sudoers file :
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

$service jenkins start
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing commands via ssh, you need to check the "Exec in pty" option.
[image]